# IntelliJ has been deleting my project file, and now it deleted my ENTIRE PROJECT

Tags: intellij-idea

I don't know what to say, nor what additional details to provide. My entire code is gone, my entire project, my entire work. I have nothing to paste because everything is deleted.
Can someone tell me how I can discern what the f*** is happening?

At first, one .fxml file kept being deleted repeatedly every time I would run the code.
Now, my ENTIRE PROJECT got deleted and I am totally lost.
The file that kept being deleted over and over again was inside of a package which contained other classes and another .fxml file which weren't ever deleted.

I am developing a JavaFX application.

UPDATE: All of the .fxml files of the project (.fxml files in all packages) got deleted physically from my SSD. So did my "lib"(which did contained active libraries) and my database file.
Only the class files have remained on the disk within the folder structer as they were. They are reachable through Windows explorer, but inside of InteliJ I literally saw how one by one everything was disappearing from the project structure until there was nothing left (just the "External Libraries" and the "Scratches and Consoles" are visible in the project structure).

UPDATE - 2 days later: I've not discerned the cause of all the above, but thankfully, I did push to GIT less than 5minutes to it all getting deleted. I did that because with how that single .fxml file was getting deleted I was worried of exactly what's happeneded happening, which is that my entire project gets deleted. I have sweeped through the logs and haven't found anything that seemed to be a clue as to what took place. I've restarted IntelliJ and imported the project anew, and that's what I'll end this with. I see not purpose in contacting IntelliJ support because I have no idea how to reproduce the issue.

Comment: You can try using Local History to recover the files: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/local-history.html. If the issue is reproducible, please contact support at https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/requests/new with the sample project to reproduce attached.

Comment: Definitely contact IntelliJ because I've never heard of this ever.

Comment: @CrazyCoder The "Show History" button is grayed out (IntelliJ is running with the deleted project open in it).

Comment: One potential case when it can happen is if you change the project output directory to some wrong location (like the source directory or project root), then enable the Clean output directory on rebuild and rebuild the project.

Comment: Stackoverflow isn't the Jetbrains support though.

Comment: @CrazyCoder I might've done exactly that. I don't know though, that's why I'm saying it with a might. But the thing that makes that makes me think that that is not the case is that fact that before my entire project got wiped, one single .fxml file was being deleted every time I'd run the code. It was inside of a package in which it wasn't the only file, and that very package was also inside of a package containing both other packages and classes.

Comment: We can only guess here, but this behavior looks like some external service could be deleting the files, like an antivirus that detected something suspicious in your project and decided to delete the threat.

Comment: @CrazyCoder I've checked Windows defender's protection history and there's nothing there. I realize that all you can do I guess, thanks for doing what you can.

Comment: Try inspecting idea.log and build.log files to see if there is anything related: https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/207241085.

Comment: I haven't found anything that to my eyes seems to have had anything to do with it all..

Comment: Is there any code in your project that can delete files?

Comment: There isn't. There is no code that works with folders/files in my code in any way (other than an SQLite database).

Comment: No more ideas. Feel free to contact support if you have more details.

Comment: Thank you on your help.